# Swing Help in paste text

Tags: java

I am a beginner. That problem happen in java swing. I do not know what's wrong...

when I click paste in my simple app , the program pastes the text twice and I have no reason for that. I use Vs code to write code java and I use java 17 now.. with java swing
how I fix it?
and What happened?
this is my Code :

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.*;
public class SimpleNotePad {
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame(" AndWorld");
    static Font newFont = new Font("Arail", Font.BOLD, 17);
    static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(); 
    static JScrollPane textAreaScrol = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    static JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        makeFrame();
    }

    public static void makePopupMenu() {
        JMenuItem cut = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem paste = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        JMenuItem selectAll = new JMenuItem("Select All");
        
        cut.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.cut();
            }
        });

        paste.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.paste();
            }
        });

        copy.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.copy();
            }
        });

        selectAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.selectAll();
            }
        });
        
        paste.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.paste();
            }
        });
        
        popupMenu.add(cut);
        popupMenu.add(copy);
        popupMenu.add(paste);
        popupMenu.addSeparator();
        popupMenu.add(selectAll);
    }
    public static void makeTextArea() {
        textArea.setFont(newFont);
        textArea.add(popupMenu);

        textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    popupMenu.show(textArea, e.getX(), e.getY());
                }               
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub            
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub            
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub            
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub               
            }
        });
    }
    
    public static void makeFrame() {
        makeTextArea();
        makePopupMenu();

        frame.add(textAreaScrol);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help me.

Comment: You are adding an action listener `paste.addActionListener(e -> textArea.paste());` twice. Side note: avoid all those static fields.

Comment: So, What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You add two action listeners so both of them respond. Remove one of the two `paste.addActionListener(e -> textArea.paste());`

Comment: not work... same problem :(

Comment: It does work. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in my comment you were adding an action listener twice so you get 2 responses for every action. 
I also removed all static modifiers in the following mre:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
 
public class SimpleNotePad {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(" AndWorld");
    Font newFont = new Font("Arail", Font.BOLD, 17);
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane textAreaScrol = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleNotePad().makeFrame();
    }

    public void makePopupMenu() {
        JMenuItem cut = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem paste = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        JMenuItem selectAll = new JMenuItem("Select All");

        cut.addActionListener(e -> textArea.cut());

        paste.addActionListener(e -> textArea.paste());

        copy.addActionListener(e -> textArea.copy());

        selectAll.addActionListener(e -> textArea.selectAll());

        //all you need to do is remove this redundant line
        //paste.addActionListener(e -> textArea.paste());

        popupMenu.add(cut);
        popupMenu.add(copy);
        popupMenu.add(paste);
        popupMenu.addSeparator();
        popupMenu.add(selectAll);

    }

    public void makeTextArea() {
        textArea.setFont(newFont);
        textArea.add(popupMenu);

        textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                   if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                       popupMenu.show(textArea, e.getX(), e.getY());
                   }
               }
        });
    }
 
    public void makeFrame() {
        makeTextArea();
        makePopupMenu();

        frame.add(textAreaScrol);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started the program and everything works normally for me, I don't know how it can be, I use NetBeans.
However, I noticed that you have an excess of code, try deleting it and running it again

```
 import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class SimpleNotePad {
        static JFrame frame = new JFrame(" AndWorld");
        static Font newFont = new Font("Arail", Font.BOLD, 17);
        static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(); 
        static JScrollPane textAreaScrol = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        static JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            makeFrame();
        }
    
        public static void makePopupMenu() {
            JMenuItem cut = new JMenuItem("Cut");
            JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
            JMenuItem paste = new JMenuItem("Paste");
            JMenuItem selectAll = new JMenuItem("Select All");
            
            cut.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    textArea.cut();
                }
            });
    
            paste.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    textArea.paste();
                }
            });
    
            copy.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    textArea.copy();
                }
            });
    
            selectAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    textArea.selectAll();
                }
            });
            
            paste.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ //HERE
                                                            //HERE
                @Override                                 //HERE
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//HERE
                    textArea.paste();//HERE
                }                                              //HERE
            });                                              //HERE
            
            popupMenu.add(cut);
            popupMenu.add(copy);
            popupMenu.add(paste);
            popupMenu.addSeparator();
            popupMenu.add(selectAll);
        }
        public static void makeTextArea() {
            textArea.setFont(newFont);
            textArea.add(popupMenu);
    
            textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
    
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                        popupMenu.show(textArea, e.getX(), e.getY());
                    }               
                }
    
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub            
                }
    
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub            
                }
    
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub            
                }
    
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub               
                }
            });
        }
        
        public static void makeFrame() {
            makeTextArea();
            makePopupMenu();
    
            frame.add(textAreaScrol);
            frame.setSize(600, 400);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```